# Excel VBA Hyperlinked Macros

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a workbook with the first sheet being a "template" sheet that I make a copy of before entering all of the data.  This first template sheet has a hyperlinked macro that works fine if I'm entering date into the template sheet, but when I make a copy and use the hyperlink, it jumps back to the template sheet and runs from there.

Here is the code I'm using, which is written in the Sheet1 Objects area (rather than a module), which might be where I'm going wrong but the hyperlink doesn't seem to work if written in the ThisWorkbook Objects area.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If Target.Range.Address = "$U$5" Then
        Dim MyDir
        MyDir = Range("T5").Value
        Select Case MyDir
            Case "N":
                Range("B3:E3,C10,C16:D16,H3:K3,I10,I16:J16,N3:Q3,O10,O16:P16").Select
                Range("B3").Activate
            Case "S":
                Range("B4:E4,C11,C19:D19,H4:K4,I11,I19:J19,N4:Q4,O11,O19:P19").Select
                Range("B4").Activate
            Case "E":
                Range("B5:E5,C12,C22:D22,H5:K5,I12,I22:J22,N5:Q5,O12,O22:P22").Select
                Range("B5").Activate
            Case "W":
                Range("B6:E6,C13,C25:D25,H6:K6,I13,I25:J25,N6:Q6,O13,O25:P25").Select
                Range("B6").Activate
            Case Else
                MsgBox "No Direction Entered"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't want to use buttons or Activex/Forms buttons and need it to be a hyperlink (as once I enter the data I need, that copied sheet then itself gets copied into another workbook, which would copy any buttons or controls with it and I don't want to have to remember to delete them every time I finish a form).

Is there any way to have the copied hyperlinked macro work in the copied sheet without having it go back to the original Template sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it would work for your use case, but you can use a hyperlink to trigger a regular function...

For example, in a cell:

```
=HYPERLINK("#DoSomething()","Do Something")
```

In a regular module:

```
Public Function doSomething()

    'you can use Application.Caller to get the triggering cell:
    Debug.Print "doSomething", Application.Caller.Address, Application.Caller.Parent.name
    Set doSomething = Selection.Offset(0, 1) 'or wherever you want to link to

End Function
```